# Cannot consume message

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have an API which takes a Message object as input produces a message to Kafka. I wrote a consumer aswell, which consumes the message and saves it to the db. My producer works as intended but the consumer does not work, For now I wanted to log a String when the message is consumed, but it is never consumed somehow, because I do not get the String.

I am running this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
```

My ProducerService

```
val headers : MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
headers[KafkaHeaders.TOPIC] = topicName
kafkaTemplate.send(GenericMessage<Message>(message, headers))
```

ProducerConfig:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaProducerConfig {

    private val kafkaServer: String = "localhost:9092"
    @Bean
    fun kafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<String, String> {
        return KafkaTemplate(producerConfig())
    }

    @Bean
    fun producerConfig(): ProducerFactory<String, String> {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        val config: MutableMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
        config[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = kafkaServer
        config[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
        config[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = JsonSerializer::class.java
        //Uncomment the below if you want to send String instead of an Object through Kafka
        //config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(config)
    }
```

ConsumerConfig:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    private val kafkaServer: String = "localhost:9092"
    private val kafkaGroupId : String = "test-consumer-group"

    @Bean
    fun consumerConfig(): ConsumerFactory<String?, Message?>{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        val config: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        config[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = kafkaServer
        config[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = kafkaGroupId
        config[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        config[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = JsonDeserializer::class.java
        return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Message>(config, null, JsonDeserializer<Message>(Message::class.java))
    }

    @Bean
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(): KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String?, Message?>>? {
        val listener: ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message>()
        listener.consumerFactory = consumerConfig()
        return listener
    }
```

And my ConsumerService:

```
@Service
class KafkaConsumerService {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerService::class.java)

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["mytopic"], groupId = "test-consumer-group")
    fun receiveData(message: Message) {
        logger.info("Data - $message received")
        
    }
```

I was expecting to get a log message when producing a message but the producing works but it doesnt seem to consume the message I dont get the log message.

Comment: How do you add topic to kafka?

Comment: I was thinking about that aswell but the Producer creates the topic for me I guess, because when I access the Kafka Server via Control Center I can see my produced messages in the topic called mytopic

Comment: Show the output of describing the consumer group, please

Comment: _consumes the message and saves it to the db_ - ideally, you should be using Kafka Connect for this, not Spring app

Comment: I dont know why but know it works somehow

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am just reading about it but could noq quite figure out how I can include it in my docker compose file

Comment: There's nothing to change in the compose file. You exec into the Kafka container and use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`.

Comment: @OneCricketeer What does that shell script exactly do, does it configure the Kafka Connect for me?

Comment: No. It tells you if there are messages in the topic available for your group to consume. You may also want to configure `auto.offset.reset` for your app

Comment: I was asking how I can include Kafka Connect to m DOcker compose file, if I want to save this to db